# Not able view the Japanese characters as an attachment in Case

Tags: apex-email-service, email2case, character-encoding

In my org , the Email to Case is handled by Apex Email Service. Whenever i create the record by sending email and In the case record , I'm able to see the Japanese character in the detail page. But in that case record, an attachment is there which is an email attachment that contains Japanese characters inside that. However those characters are scrambled to view. Can anyone suggest any ideas to overcome this.

[image]

Comment: IS it pdf or excel

Comment: Its just a text doc